# refreshApex not updating datatable

Tags: refreshapex

wire method retrieves values for datatable  -

```js
@track wrapperList;
@track error;

@wire(getQuestions,{userId:Id})
wiredQuestions{(data,error)}{

// i already tried
this.wrapperList = data;

 if(data){

this.wrapperList = data;

}
if(error){

this.error = error;

}
}

from a separate function -
removeQuestion()

.then(()=>{
this.showToast('Success');})

return refreshApex(this.wrapperList); // -> doesn't refresh the data
```

Comment: yes, I came across that thread and resolved my issues this morning. Thanks for responding !

Comment: Actually, I realized refreshApex only updates wired params. How would I call apexRefresh on this.wrapper here ?      `@wire(apexMethod, (param1:value1}) wiredrecords(result){ this.wireddataresult = result; const{data,error} = result; if(data) this.wrapper = data.map((each) => ({...each, isOpen:true}));}`.  apexRefresh(this.wireddataresult) = >works, apexRefresh(this.wrapper) does not update the table. How should I update this.wrapper? this.wrapper is what is used to populate datatable.

Comment: ah, i figured it out. my save function was not triggering the refresh correctly. This worked for me -  `save({}) .then((result) =>{this.showToast('Success");return refreshApex(this.wireddataresult);}